# Sessions connected to a pluggable database in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, session, oracle12c, pluggable

Is there a way of identifying the connections made to a pluggable Oracle database? I can use the `v$sessions` and `v$process` views, but this seems to show all sessions within the container and all pluggable databases (with no indication on those views as to which database the session is linked to).

Any ideas?

Comment: Just adding one more info: If you want to know which container(database) the session is linked to you can run `SHOW CON_NAME`. This will provide the container name. More info [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-connecting-to-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the column SERVICE_NAME of v$session to identify to which service a session is connected to. Each PDB has at least one service name.
You can set more than one service name for a PDB but this might still help.

Comment: great i can use that, i didn't spot that column. Thanks.